# HDFS Folder in to a key-value hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, hiveql

I have the following folder structure in the HDFS:

- Polygons

  - file1.kml
  - file2.kml
  - file3.kml

and I want to load it into a hive table with the following schema:

Table "Polygons":

```
name|kml
file1|content of file1
file2|content of file2
file3|content of file3
```

How can this be done in Hive ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To best of my knowledge it's not possible only using `Hive`. But you can certainly make use of `bash` (I suppose it's a Linux machine). First create the input file, eg :

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # the dir path to be passed as parameter 
 for file in $1/*
    do echo "$(basename $file)|$(cat $file)" >> polygons.dat
 done
```

After giving the execution permission to the script, run it as :

```
 ./script Polygons
```

Now you will have the required data in the `polygons.dat` file. If it's a Windows machine, you have to find out a way to do the same using `batch` script (I afraid I won't be able to help then).

Then use the basic `Hive` commands to do the loading, eg :

```
 hive> CREATE TABLE Polygons ( name STRING, kml STRING)
     >   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
     >   FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
     >   STORED AS TEXTFILE;

 hive> LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'path/polygons.dat' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE Polygons;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of **INPUT__FILE__NAME**, its a virtual column in hive that stores the file name

Check this [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VirtualColumns) for more info about this virtual column.

You can load the data into a table, then in the select query you can use INPUT__FILE__NAME to get the file name.

e.g.,

```
select INPUT__FILE__NAME,your_column from your_table;
```